# Website/app to geocode accurate co-ords from an address?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Ok i've tried a couple and they've been miles out.

I don't need anything automated or any json / xml etc just a good website where i can paste in an address, receive co-ords and then paste elsewhere.

anyone recommend a good one?

Comment: These sorts of "list" or "recommendation" questions should be CW (hence my making my answer CW). Please edit the question and tick the box.

Comment: What geographical constraints do you have? I.e. is this (say) only for UK addresses?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you know this is an inexact science, sometimes markedly so.

I've generally been pretty happy with [GeoBytes' IP Locator](http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing street addresses this site will give you the XY with an option to view on Google or Bing maps.  It does single addresses and batch geocoding.

https://webgis.usc.edu/Services/Geocode/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you will find any free service that provide consistently accurate data for residential addresses.  If I'm wrong, I'd like to know.  The reason is that there is not (for the US) a central list of geocoordinates for addresses.  What they usually have is the house number range by block, and interpolate to find an approximate location.  As you get to less densely populated areas with bigger blocks, or older sections of town with non-uniformly spaced addresses, these get less accurate.  Businesses are different, as there are much fewer, and I know that there are geolocated business databases, although the examples that I've seen are not cheap.